# Passing value from angular to webapi put method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass id value from angular code to asp.net web api. I tried couple of ways but still unable to pass the value. What may be the code issue?

Angular Service code

```
angular.module('myServiceApp')
.factory('mySvc', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        startJob: function (id) {
            return $http.put('/api/Job/Put/' + id);
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML Code

```
<div ng-click="initiateJob(id)">
Start Now
</div>
```

Angular Function

```
$scope.initiateJob = function (id) {
    mySvc.startJob(id)
         .success(function () {
             alert('started successfully');
         }).error(function (err) {
             $scope.error = err;                
         });
}
```

webapi code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;           
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Try this: $http.put('/api/Job/Put/', {}, {params: {id: id}}). On the server side the request object must be available. Syntax for angular $http here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put. Above the "Methods" block you'll find description for config object (3rd parameter in put method).

Comment: @IvanMalenko, Why not editing it and formulating it as an answer ?

Comment: @OrelEraki, it's not an answer. Just a reference on the documentation with small comment on code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
return $http.put('/api/Job/Put/' + id);
```

Into this:

```
return $http.put('/api/Job/' + id);
```

I did this on my side and it works just fine, here's a complete example:

**WEB API Controller:**

```
public class JobController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        return response;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app', []);

    angular.module("app").controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

        $scope.CallPut = function () {

            debugger

            var id = 1;

            $http.put("/api/Job/" + id).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;

            });
        }
    });

</script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div id="mainController" ng-controller="mainController">
        <input type="button" ng-click="CallPut()" value="Call Put" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Also make sure you have a file called WebApiConfig.cs in the App_Start folder of your project where you define web api routes and makes sure you reister your web api routes **BEFORE** the MVC routes in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```